# Double vs SIngle Quotes issue

Tags: php, html

Can someone help me to write this correct, i am strugling. And could someone explain to me how to combine single and double quotes in best way???
I have issue in line

```
value = "<?php echo $client['name_'.$key];?>"
```

my whole code is

```
<?php
    foreach($this->config->item('languages') as $key=>$value)
    {
        echo '<div id="edit-fragment-'.$key.'">
        <table class="form_horizontal" width="100%">

        <tr>
            <td class="field">'.lang('polls_txt_title').'</td>
            <td class="value"><input type="text" name="client_'.$key.'" value = "<?php echo $client['name_'.$key];?>"; /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="field">'.lang('polls_txt_vote').'</td>
            <td class="value"><input type="text" name="polls_'.$key.'_vote" value="'.$this->mConfig->item('polls_'.$key.'_vote').'" /></td>
        </tr>



        </table>
        </div>';
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like

```
value = "<?php echo $client['name_'.$key];?>";
```

As per your edited question see my second answer

```
'<td class="value"><input type="text" name="client_'.$key.'" value = "'.$client['name_'.$key].'" /></td>'
```

Comment: sorry this is value in html in input tag

Comment: Syntax error forgot the closing semi-colon $client['name_'.$key] *;*

Comment: It is not our mistake that ans is not working.We have given ans as per your previous question.Let us give a new one for your new question

Comment: @ Gautam3164 i think it issue with other lines your code is correct

Answer (score 1):

You could do either...

```
<input value="<?php echo $client['name_'.$key]; ?>" />
```

...or...

```
<?php echo "<input value=".$client['name_'.$key]." />"; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is `<input value="" />`

Your PHP is `<?php echo $client["name_" . $key];?>`

Together it'd be `<input value="<?php echo $client["name_" . $key];?>" />`

Your problem is incorrect php syntax in your code. With the correct syntax you don't even need different (i.e. both double and single) quotes.

Answer (score -2):

Change to:

```
value = "<?php echo $client['name_'.$key]; ?>"
```

or if short tags are enabled

```
value = "<?=$client['name_'.$key];?>"
```

Comment: sorry thos is not correct see you gave 3 single qoutes